# How to have vertical lines seperate css grid elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with 3 columns and want to have two vertical lines to separate the elements.

So far, I simply created two `span` element and placed them between the grid elements using css.

```
.vertical_line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: black;
}

#v1 {
  left: 33.33%;
}

#v2 {
  left: 66.33%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0mg12etr/

Changing the number of columns will be annoying with my method and it works nicely only if the width of the elements are known.

Is there a neater way to achieve this?

Comment: you want a solution that works with any number of columns?

Comment: I feel a background gradient coming! ☺

Comment: You can put border right on every element instead of last one, you can achieve this with css, .classname:last-child{border-right: none;}, while that same class will have .className{border-right: 1px solid }

Comment: @Paulie_D I was tempted ;) let's first have more details before unleashing the gradients :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want? Think its a way you want to do with no spans and using ::after

```css
.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-element {
  align-self: center;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(2n+3)::after{
  content:'';
  width:1px;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-7px;
  top:0;
}
#v1 {
  left: 33.33%;
}

#v2 {
  left: 66.33%;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with flex.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  text-align:center;
}
.column:nth-child(odd) {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.column + .column {
  border-left:2px solid red;
}

html, body {
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    col1 row1
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    col2 row1
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    col3 row1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    col1 row2
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    col2 row2
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    col3 row2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could have your vertical lines be inserted between your different elements instead of having them at the start and using absolute positions. You might need to wrap everything in a container to keep the grid containers and the vertical lines inline.

For exemple something like this :

```
<div class="global-container">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-container">
    <span class="vertical_line"></span>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-container">
    <span class="vertical_line"></span>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
      <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-container">
<\div>
```

You'd have to modify some other css tho : https://jsfiddle.net/6ocyr5b9/8/